# My variable can't hold "document.querySelector(".content") " , it returns null

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="domManipulating.js"></script>    
</head>

// The DOM
<body>
  <h1>
    THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
  </h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="content">
      This is the glorious text-content!
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my JS

```
var content = document.querySelector(".content");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

paragraph.textContent = " Hey I'm red";

content.appendChild(paragraph);
```

When I use the console to test my code a error appears :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

From my understanding the variable `content` can't hold `document.querySelector(".content")`

When I write `document.querySelector(".content")`in the console it actually works but when I use `var paragraph = document.createElement("p");`the variable turns into a null.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `<script src="domManipulating.js"></script>` loading before DOM is ready. In that case `document.querySelector` will not able to find the element from the DOM

One alternative is to load the script just before closing `body` tag

```
<body>
   //html tags
<script src="domManipulating.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
var content = document.querySelector(".content");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");

paragraph.textContent = " Hey I'm red";

content.appendChild(paragraph);
```

```html
<h1>
  THE TITLE OF YOUR WEBPAGE
</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is the glorious text-content!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I tested and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the location of your `script` tag in your HTML: it's *above* the body. At the time the script runs, the body (and all of its content, including `.content`) has not been created yet.

Either wrap your whole script in a function that runs once the document is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var content = document.querySelector('.content');
  // ...
```

or, a better option: give your script the `defer` attribute, and it'll automatically run only once the document is ready to be parsed:

```
<head>
<script src="domManipulating.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I didn't know about these options, feels great knowing that they exist. Thank you!